# bootstrap-select selects a wrong option each time.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap select  Bootstrap-select v1.7.2 in Angular. When I select some option from drop down it selects some other option.

Plunker is setup here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HPPlxx?p=preview

(code is in dashboard.html and dashboard.js)

That's how I am creating it. bootstrap-dropdown is the directive that initiates the drop-down.

```
  <form role="form" name="frmVariableConfig" ng-submit="vm.saveChanges()">
        <select ng-model="vm.CurrCustomer.Logic" name="ddlLogic" check-validation class="validate[required]" bootstrap-dropdown >
           <option ng-repeat="logic in vm.Logics" value="{{logic.value}}">{{logic.displayName}}</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm text-right">Save</button>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-options to populate the option elements of a select input.

Like so:

```
<select ng-model="vm.CurrCustomer.Logic" data-ng-options="logic.displayName for logic in vm.Logics track by logic.value" name="ddlLogic" check-validation class="validate[required]" bootstrap-dropdown >
    <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>
```

---

**EDIT**

Use the following:

```
<select ng-model="vm.CurrCustomer.Logic" data-ng-options="logic.displayName for logic in vm.Logics" check-validation class="validate[customFunc]" bootstrap-dropdown>
         <option style="display:none" value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

where `customFunc` is a new custom validation function you create to check that the selected value is not `""`.

Comment: it worked but then validation class="validate[required]" has no effect. means it is calling the submit function even when the select is required. if i take out  <option value="">Select...</option>        validation works but then i get the same behavior of wrong selection .

Comment: Ok I did some digging: the problem is the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Comment: This empty option is then being processed by the bootstrap-dropdown directive as an actual option. Specifically it is present in the DOM at the time the bootstrap dropdown js is run and it reads it as an actual option.

Comment: i did that         vm.CurrCustomer.Logic =  vm.Logics[0].value;  here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HPPlxx?p=preview   its something wrong with the validation engine i guess.

Comment: Yeah check my EDIT in the main post as to what I suggest doing.

Comment: this custom action should be created in validation engine's js ?

Comment: You should never edit third party code in your solutions (for reasons such as if you were to then update that library then you would lose your own code). The custom function should be in one of your files. How to wire up the validation to a custom function of this sort is beyond my knowledge. I would recommend looking through the docs as I am sure it is quite commonly needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem. You need a blank state option. Also it helps to use ng-options rather than using ng-repeat in the option. Hope this solves your problem!

```
<div ng-controller="dashboard as vm">
   <div class="block-area">
      <div class="row col-md-12 ">
         <h3 class="block-title">  {{vm.title}}</h3>
         <form role="form" name="frmVariableConfig" ng-submit="vm.saveChanges()">
            <select required ng-model="vm.CurrCustomer.Logic" name="ddlLogic" check-validation class="validate[required]" ng-options="logic.displayName for logic in vm.Logics track by logic.displayName" bootstrap-dropdown >
               <option value="">Pick One</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm text-right">Save</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked but then validation class="validate[required]" has no effect. means it is calling the submit function even when the select is required. if i take out  <option value="">Select...</option>        validation works but then i get the same behavior of wrong selection .

Comment: You can add `required` to `<select>` and it prevents submission. But the validation doesn't seem to fire correctly. What exactly are you trying to show in the validation? Is there a specific reason you are using these directives instead of just using the bootstrap CSS with `ng-options` and `ng-form`?

Comment: Yes my form uses jquery validation engine and select is a bootstrap select. Both the directives actually initiates them. Check-validation initiates jquery validation engine and other one intimates bootstrap- select

Comment: Yes I see both of those, I'm just curious whether it's actually necessary to use both/either of those (validation engine and select is a bootstrap select). It seems like both of their functions can be replicated with the AngularJS library.  
Specially:  
[FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) and [ModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: My SPA was made using a html5 template and that template uses these plugins and i am awake countless nights to deal with them in Angular.

Comment: Apologize @RaasMasood I did not mean offense, I know how template integrated directives can be constraining. After going through your plunkr thoroughly though, I would strongly recommend switching to an angular based plugin such as [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/). Angular modules are much easier to deal with in a SPA than jQuery and Bootstrap plugins wrapped in an angular directive. It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I guess that's an excellent advice. Will definitely consider it